# Send variables to a template from setting.py

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, mapbox

I'm triyng to send two variables from settings.py to a template. At the end of settings.py I've putted that variables:

**settings.py**

```
.
.
.
# MapBox Studio
mapbox_user = 'a_string'
mapbox_token = 'a_string'
```

Then I've created a context_processors:

**context_processors.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

def mapbox_data(request):
    mapbox_user = settings.mapbox_user
    mapbox_token = settings.mapbox_token
    context = {
        'mapbox_user': mapbox_user,
        'mapbox_token': mapbox_token,
    }
    return context
```

And at the end I've putted it inside context_processors list:

```
    'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        # project context
        'webgis.context_processors.mapbox_data',
    ],
```

Now I use `{{ mapbox_user }}` and `{{ mapbox_token }}` inside my template.

```
var outDoors = new ol.layer.Tile({
  type: 'base',
  title: 'Topographic',
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      attributions: 'powered with <a href="https://openlayers.org/" target="_blank">OpenLayers</a>',
      url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{{ mapbox_user }}/'
          + 'cjxkimp5j5s0o1ct4b68n4x1p/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?'
          + 'access_token={{ mapbox_token }}'
    }),
});
```

But I see this error:

> AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'mapbox_user'

It is the first time that I try to pass data from settings.py to a template. What I've wrong?
If I use `mapbox_user` and `mapbox_token` directly into HTML I can see my map without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the variable in upper case in the `settings.py` file.

**Use**:

```
MAPBOX_USER = 'a_string'
MAPBOX_TOKEN = 'a_string'
```